# How to read a file using sudo?

Tags: sudo, cat

As part of an lab that I am doing titled "sudo", one of the questions is, "What is the password in the `secret.txt` file?".

When I try `cat secret.txt` I get a permission denied message.

When I try `sudo cat secret.txt` I get asked for a password.

I have tried to change permissions: not permitted.

Is there any other way of reading files?

Comment: this lab on sudo, does it talk about passwords at all?

Comment: Sudo can be configured in lots of different ways, but usually it is asking for the same password you used to login. Your starting point for accessing the file is to look at the ownership and permissions (ls). If you can't access the file with your login, check `sudo -l` to see what elevated permissions sudo has been configured with for your account.

Comment: Was this lab on sudo accompanied by a reference to a textbook or lecture?

Comment: No mention of passwords or references. The lab is called “sudo elevated privileges”.  I log into the lab and I’m straight into a terminal screen. I type ls and see the file that I’m supposed to look at.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to change permissions on the file if you're not the file's owner, or root.

When you use `sudo cat secret.txt` and `sudo` asks for a password, it is (normally) *your* password it is asking for.

If you give the correct password (yours) and if `sudo` has been set up to allow you to use it, then that command would show the contents of the file `secret.txt`. If you are not allowed to use `sudo` and if you don't know the root password, then you will not be able to read the file by normal means.

Comment: That depends on whether `sudo` has been configured to prompt for your password or the password of the target user (here not specified, generally defaults to `root`). See `targetpw`/`runaspw`/`rootpw`... in the  `sudoers(5)` man page.

Comment: with the minor caveat of a possible `rootpw` configuration (or even more obscurely, `runaspw` / `runas_default`)